# format numbers or string to currencies in python

Tags: python

I run into the following error when attempting to format string in python,

```
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to tuple.__format__

def prop_details(address):

    if address:

       mv = 216164970,
       av = 191088,
       totalsqft = 663487

    return ("${:,.0f}".format(mv), "${:,.0f}".format(av), totalsqft)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you write:

```py
mv = 216164970,
```

then `mv` becomes a `tuple`.

Try without the comma...

Also, I find the [f-string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) clearer. You may want to take advantage of it if you are using Python >=3.6:

```py
def prop_details(address):
    if address:
        mv = 216164970
        av = 191088
        totalsqft = 663487
    else:
        mv, av, totalsqft = 0, 0, 0
    return f'${mv:,.0f}', f'${av:,.0f}', totalsqft

>>> prop_details(1)
('$216,164,970', '$191,088', 663487)
```